# SQLModel Relationship that returns count of related objects

Tags: python, fastapi, sqlmodel

I'm working on a FastAPI application and using SQLModel with a Postgres backend. I have `Post` objects, each of which can be upvoted by `User`s. We represent this with a `PostUpvote` many-to-many relation between `User`s and `Post`s. So far, so boring.

```
from datetime import datetime
from typing import List, Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel
from sqlmodel import Field, Relationship, SQLModel
import uuid as uuid_pkg

def uuid_hex():
    return uuid_pkg.uuid4().hex

def PkIdField():
    return Field(
        default_factory=uuid_hex,
        primary_key=True,
        index=True,
        nullable=False,
    )

class PostBase(SQLModel):
    title: str
    description: str

class Post(PostBase, table=True):
    creator_id: str = Field(foreign_key="amp_users.id")
    id: str = PkIdField()
    created_at: datetime = Field(default_factory=datetime.utcnow, nullable=False)
    creator: User = Relationship(back_populates="posts")
    upvotes: List["PostUpvote"] = Relationship(back_populates="post")

class UserBase(SQLModel):
    email: str

class User(UserBase, table=True):
    # "user" table is reserved by postgres
    __tablename__ = "app_users"
    id: str = PkIdField()
    posts: List["Post"] = Relationship(back_populates="creator")

class PostUpvote(SQLModel, table=True):
    post: Post = Relationship(back_populates="upvotes")
    post_id: str = Field(foreign_key="posts.id", primary_key=True)
    user_id: str = Field(foreign_key="app_users.id", primary_key=True)
```

As you can see, I've set up an `upvotes` relationship on my `Post` object, which will give me a list of all the upvotes for that post. But when I'm returning this to the frontend, I don't need or want a list of all the upvotes. I just need the count. Obviously, I can use `len(post.updates)` to get this, but that still requires us to fetch all the individual upvote objects for that post. So my question is, is there some way to add an `upvote_count` relationship to my `Post` object, like so:

```
class Post(PostBase, table=True):
    creator_id: str = Field(foreign_key="amp_users.id")
    id: str = PkIdField()
    created_at: datetime = Field(default_factory=datetime.utcnow, nullable=False)
    creator: User = Relationship(back_populates="posts")
    upvotes: List["PostUpvote"] = Relationship(back_populates="post")
    upvote_count: int = Relationship(...)
```

Note that this is using SQLModel's `Relationship` feature (https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/relationship-attributes/), not SQLAlchemy relations (though I am running SQLAlchemy under the hood).

If there's some way to provide a custom SQLAlchemy query to the SQLModel relationship, that would solve the problem neatly. But I've not been able to find anything in the SQLModel docs about how to do so. Is this even possible? Or should I just resign myself to doing the query manually?

Comment: Unfortunately not. These are Relationships as defined by SQLModel, not SQLAlchemy (though I am running SQLAlchemy under the hood).

Comment: However, if there were some way to supply that SA relationship to SQLModel that *would* solve the problem.